# Mail notification shows new email, quickly disappears and email is missing

Tags: mail.app, email

Any email I get pops up a notification in the upper-right corner of my screen, as per the native notification settings in the Apple Mail app. Every now and then I will get a quick notification indicating a new email, but then the email notification (and email) will quickly disappear. It's almost as if it was "recalled" by the email server and removed from my machine.

I haven't been able to find any consistency in the type of email that is received - I usually only get a glimpse of who sent it (always a company, never a personal one, at least not that I've noticed) and it's not like the ones that disappear are always from the same place or anything.

The emails in question are from one of my gmail accounts. I have no filters or manually-added spam blockers or blacklisted emails set up in that account, and I've got the email set up with IMAP into Apple's Mail client.

Anyone seen anything like this before? Any ideas of how to stop having these emails disappear?

Comment: Who is your email provider?  Also, do you you have any filters and/or spam controls thru your email provider?

Comment: @Tyson I have two gmail accounts set up through Mail, and I just checked and had some filters set up in one of my addresses that added labels to the emails, but nothing that moved its location, and no blocks. The other account has neither filters nor blocks. (And that second one is the one I think is having emails disappear).

Comment: If you edit that into your question it will add needed info and raise your question to the top of the active page again. You should also indicate if you have the accounts set up as IMAP or POP3.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I cant figure it out. It is instantly going away the moment it hits my gmail